# How can I make my subclasses more efficient?

Tags: python, inheritance, init, superclass

I'm creating a game and for the units/characters I have a base class called Unit that looks like this.

```
class Unit:
    def __init__(self, name, ally=False):
        self.ac = 10
        self._name = name
        self.name = self._name
        self.ally = ally
        self._hp = 10
        self.hp = self._hp
        self._str = 0
        self.str = self._str
        self._dex = 0
        self.dex = self._dex
        self._con = 0
        self.con = self._con
```

the self._stat is supposed to represent the base stat without buffs or debuffs, the default value, and self.stat being the one used and changed throughout the game.

I then have sub_classes that use Unit as the Base class, like this.

```
class Fighter(Unit):
    def __init__(self, name, ally=False):
        super().__init__(name, ally)
        self._con = 3
        self.con = self._con
        self._hp = 10 + self._con
        self.hp = self._hp
        self._str = 3
        self.str = self._str
        self._dex = 1
        self.dex = self._dex
```

But I would prefer it if I could minimize how much I need to rewrite for the **init** method for my subclasses, I thought that since the self.stat attrs referenced the self._stat on creation I'd be able to do something more like this

```
class Fighter(Unit):
    def __init__(self, name, ally=False):
        super().__init__(name, ally)
        self._con = 3
        self._hp = 10 + self._con
        self._str = 3
        self._dex = 1
```

and thought that since the self.stat attrs reference the self._stat for assignment, I could just change the assignment for self._stat and it would adjust everything how I need it to, however that's not what happens and if I just change self._stat then self.stat remains the same as the Base class, only changing the self._stat.

Is there a different way I can structure this to make the stat assignments easier and less wordy when making my new classes?

Comment: You could try using the [`@property` wrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)  for your attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You should design your classes in more abstract way to achieve your goal. Let's take a look at the "hp" thing.

We can see that Unit has a specific amount of hp, as well as warrior. Also we can see, that you add "con" value to the hp for the Warrior. We can also see, that Unit has "con = 0". So actually, we can rewrite it:

```
>>> class Unit:
...     def __init__(self, name, hp, con):
...             self.name = name
...             self._name = name
...             self.hp = hp + con
...             self._hp = hp
...             self.con = con
...             self._con = con


>>> class Warrior(Unit):
...     pass
```

Now we can see that basically this classes equal to each other, because Warrior class does not provide any additional logic. So please note, that you should do it only for the cases, where subclasses expand their parent logic.

Now if you want to override some class-specific logic, you should use Unit as abstract class.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod, abstractproperty


class Unit:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, name, hp, con):
        self.name = name
        self._name = name 
        self.con = con
        self._con = con
        self._hp, self.hp = self._init_hp(hp)

    @abstractmethod
    def heal():
    """Heal unit"""

    @abstractmethod
    def _init_hp():
    """Calculate self._hp and self.hp values"""


class Warrior(Unit):
    def heal(self):
        self.hp += 5

    def _init_hp(self, hp):
        """Just an example, no logic here"""
        return hp, hp * 2 + self.con


class Villager(Unit):
    def heal(self):
        self.hp += 1

    def _init_hp(self, hp):
        """Just an example, no logic here"""
        return hp / 2, hp - 1
```

Comment: I'll have to play around with this and test some things out but it's definitely given me an idea about some things to try out, thank you!